# Can I equip 2 Mist Talisman?

Tags: guild-wars-2

If I purchase 2 Mist Talisman trinkets from the PvP League Vendor, can I equip both in the same character?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this list on the wiki](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Unique) of unique items, you can wear two Mist Talisman. Normally ascended items are unique, such that you can only equip one of them (which is why earlier ascended accessories come in pairs).